# Cannot access a non-static member of outer type X via nested type X

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to call a method in the Main Activity to call a new Fragment using
    ((FragmentActivity)Activity).ShowFragment(new SmokeSensor());

however it throws the error:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type
>
> 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' via nested type
>
> '*******.Fragments.Dashboard.ViewAdapter`

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
public void ShowFragment(SupportFragment fragment) {
    var transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    connectionStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

    if (!ConnectionDetector.IsConnected(this)) {
        connectionStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        transaction.Detach(currentFragment);
        transaction.Commit();
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);

        return;
    }

    if (fragment == currentFragment) {
        transaction.Detach(currentFragment);
        transaction.Attach(currentFragment);
        transaction.Commit();
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);

        return;
    }

    transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in,
                                    Resource.Animation.slide_out);
    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.Commit();
    drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);
    currentFragment = fragment;
}
```

Comment: is smoke sensor a static class?

Comment: @israelaltar No, it isn't. I will actually post the full error

Comment: you cant access non-static from static. Make sure your method you are doing `((FragmentActivity)Activity).ShowFragment(new SmokeSensor());` is not static.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Nothing is static

Comment: The problem might be because I'm calling this in the overriden method `RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder` which appearantely doesn't like it

Comment: Please post a full logcat capture of the error. It's difficult to see the problem from what you've provided. Where in the source code provided does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

why you'r "Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment" can be only static in *******.Fragments.Dashboard.ViewAdapter ?

see that [cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320935/cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type-via-nested-type)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222296/c-sharp-cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type)